# Getting a error using use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Mime\TemplatedEmail and ->htmlTemplate

Tags: mailer, html-templates

I´m creating a register controller with Symfony 5.4 and when I use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Mime\TemplatedEmail and ->htmlTemplate inside a mail with (new TemplatedEmail()) I always get this error message: Call to unknown method: Symfony\Component\Mime\Email::htmlTemplate(). I don't know what to do because when I register a user, I get the same message: Expected response code "250/251/252" but got code "550", with message "550 [E3] Message rejected because sender's email is not confirmed.". I don't understand why this is happening, the sender's email is confirmed so I suppose that this error is due to something related to the class Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Mime\TemplatedEmail, maybe I'm missing something. I really appreciate your help, guys, thanks

I have tried everything, I'm desperate right now so any help will be highly welcomed, thanks

Comment: I have to add some information: though the error message (Expected response code "250/251/252" but got code "550", with message "550 [E3] Message rejected because sender's email is not confirmed."), the register works and the email and the password got stored in my database but the error is always there, thanks again

Comment: Seems like the error could be here: public function register(Request $request, UserPasswordHasherInterface $userPasswordHasher, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response, looks like something is wrong here, thanks again